# API to generate CSS in Java

Tags: java, css, api

Is there a Java API that can be used to generate CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to check Genesis. It is a library I created to generate CSS and CSS background images from Java: [http://clementbtc.github.io/genesis/](http://clementbtc.github.io/genesis/com/projetloki/genesis/Genesis.html)

Answer (score 3):

Why dont just write flat text file?

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find one.  However, if you look around, you can find plenty of tools that will generate CSS for you, some of which are written in Java.  So, in effect, you could just use one of those tools and then insert the generated CSS into whatever you wanted to use it in, or you could find a good project on sourceforge and reverse engineer it, or better yet, take a look at their source code, and create your own API out of it (and then, why not, post it online for everyone else!)